# appengine and html5 audio

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, blobstore

I'm just trying to figure out how to use the `blobstore` and `HTML5` audio.

My code is only slightly modified from working code, so it cant need major changes.

```
class data(webapp2.RequestHandler): 
def get(self):
    a = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM UserPhoto")
    blob = a[1].blob_key


    self.redirect('/Serve/%s' % blob.key())



class ServeHandler(Handler, blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
def get(self, audio_key):
    if not blobstore.get(audio_key):
        self.error(404)
    else:
        self.send_blob(audio_key)
        self.redirect('/music')

class music(Handler):
def get(self):
    self.render("music.html")
```

and this is the HTML where the audio will be played:

```
<audio controls="controls">
<source src="/Serve/%s"/>
Your browser does not support the audio element.
```

and the error is

```
"GET /Serve/%s HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: there is a slight typo in the html src with a miss placed quotation mark, but that isnt causing the error

Comment: Is the html really pointing to /Serve/%s or that is just a template? Also why are you redirecting to /music in the ServeHandler? Could you post the config of you wsgi app to see the routes. The redirect in data also seems odd,you should use instead that blob_key (which is from a UserPhoto?) to generate the music player html.

Answer (score 3):

You don't seem to have put the actual key variable in the HTML. You just have `/serve/%s` which is obviously wrong - Django templates don't even use Python string substitution, let alone the fact that you haven't given it anything to substitute.

You need to pass the blob key to the template from the `get` handler, then reference it with `<source src="/Serve/{{ blob_key }}"/>`.